# Update a table based on joining 4 tables

Tags: mysql, join, sql-update

I have the following tables:

**agent**

```
+-------------------------------------+
| id  |  name   | desc     |  comment |
|-------------------------------------+
| 1   |  agent1 | agent 1  | sss      |
| 2   |  agent2 | agent 2  | eee      |
|-------------------------------------|
```

**agent_old**

```
+-------------------------------------+
| id  |  name   | desc     |  comment |
|-------------------------------------+
| 1   |  agent1 | agent 1  | sss      |
| 2   |  agent3 | agent 3  | eee      |
|-------------------------------------|
```

**auth**

```
+-------------------------------+
| id  |  login   | password     |  
|-------------------------------+
| 1   |  agent1  | xxxxxxx      |
| 2   |  agent2  | yyyyyy       |
|-------------------------------|
```

**auth_old**

```
+-------------------------------+
| id  |  login     | password   |
|-------------------------------+
| 1   |  oldagent1 | wwwwww     |
| 2   |  oldagent2 | qqqqqq     |
|-------------------------------|
```

I need the resultant tables like this:

**agent**

```
+-------------------------------------+
| id  |  name   | desc     |  comment |
|-------------------------------------+
| 1   |  agent1 | agent 1  | sss      |
| 2   |  agent2 | agent 2  | eee      |
|-------------------------------------|
```

**auth**

```
+-------------------------------+
| id  |  login   | password     |  
|-------------------------------+
| 1   |oldagent1 | wwwwww       |
| 2   |  agent2  | yyyyyy       |
|-------------------------------|
```

This is what I have got but does not run:

```
update auth a 
set 
    a.login = oa.login, 
    a.password = oa.password 
from (
    select o.login, 
    o.password 
    from auth_old o 
    join agent na 
    join agent_old ago 
    on ago.id = o.id 
    and na.name = ago.name 
    and na.desc = ago.desc
    ) oa 
where a.id = na.id
```

Comment: Your WHERE clause should reference `oa`, not `na`

Comment: That looks like implicit join notation with it's comma's replaced with "join"; it really is a good practice to get used to modern explicit join notation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In mysql you could use  this sintax  but you have not an id in you from ( select ) oa ..  i have added  the o.id for this  (hope is the right one)

```
    update auth a 
    inner join  (
        select o.login, 
        o.password , 
        na.id
        from auth_old o 
        join agent na 
        join agent_old ago 
        on ago.id = o.id 
        and na.name = ago.name 
        and na.desc = ago.desc
        ) oa  on a.id = oa.id
    set 
        a.login = oa.login, 
        a.password = oa.password
```

*(and as suggested  by Bill Karvin you have a wrong table alias na instead of oa)*

Comment: It should be na.id not oa.id. Not sure how to achieve.  id matching should only happen between agent and auth or agent_old and auth_old

Comment: @cppcoder   .. once you have create the inner join  ( ) table_alias the reference for the column in the inner select must be based on the table_alias  .. so the ON condition can't be na.id but  oa.column_name (oa is your  table_alias)

Comment: I changed `o.id` to `na.id` in the select clause and used it to achieve my need

Comment: . have update the answer  with na.id  .. .. seems that you rarerly  ..mark the answer as acpted  or rate as usefult  .. seems not fair this me ..

Comment: Not sure why do you think that way. I have accepted answer for all the questions I ask and has got correct answer.

Comment: and mine wok or not  ..  ?  ..lead you to the right answer or not ?